# Return or not return in a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, search, return, binary-search-tree

Before asking, I searched out some old questions and get a better idea to put the "return" in front of the inside re-invocated the function to get the expected result.
some of them like:
[How to stop python recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35273905/how-to-stop-python-recursion)
[Python recursion and return statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937000/python-recursion-and-return-statements). But when I do the same thing with my problem, it gets worse.

I have a Binary Search Tree and want to get the TreeNode instance by given a node's key, so it looks an easier traversal requirement and I already easily realized similar functions below, with which I did NOT put return in front of the function:

```
#preorder_List=[]
def preorder(treeNode):
    if treeNode:
        preorder_List.append(treeNode.getKey())
        preorder(treeNode.has_left_child())
        preorder(treeNode.has_right_child())
    return preorder_List
```

so for my new requirement, I compose it like below first:

```
def getNode(treeNode,key):
    if(treeNode):
        if(treeNode.key==key):
            print("got it=",treeNode.key)
            return treeNode
        else:
            getNode(treeNode.left_child(),key)    
            getNode(treeNode.right_child(),key)
```

then the issue occurs, it finds the key/node but kept running and report a None error finally and then I put return in front of the both left and right branch like below:

```
def getNode(treeNode,key):
    if(treeNode):
        if(treeNode.key==key):
            print("got it=",treeNode.key)
            return treeNode
        else:
            return getNode(treeNode.left_child(),key)    
            return getNode(treeNode.right_child(),key)
```

but this makes the thing worse, it did reach the key found and return None earlier.

Then I tried to remove one "return" for the branch, no matter right or left. It works (Update: this worked when my test case contains only 3 nodes, when I put more nodes, it didn't work, or to say if the expected node is from right, then put return in front of right branch invocation works, for left one, it didn't). What's the better solution?

Comment: You can't return twice from the same function; once you hit the first return statement, you exit the function.

Comment: Also, what happens when there is no child to your `treeNode`?

Comment: so what's the better solution? like what I did, just put one return for any of the functions?

Comment: How about your function takes a list of `treeNode`s and recursively deals with every single one of them?

Comment: Do you expect to find only one node with the key

Comment: That's exactly what I did and I expect it returns earlier once find the key. so I need to use return in front of the function to avoid return None. But this cannot handle two branches.

Comment: Can a child be `None` or will it always be a node?  What happens if you call `treeNode.left_child()` and there isn't a left child?

Answer (score 2):

You need to be able to `return` the results of your recursive calls, but you don't always need to do so unconditionally. Sometimes you'll not get the result you need from the first recursion, so you need to recurse on the other one before returning anything.

The best way to deal with this is usually to assign the results of the recursion to a variable, which you can then test. So if `getNode` either returns a node (if it found the key), or `None` (if it didn't), you can do something like this:

```
result = getNode(treeNode.left_child(),key)    
if result is not None:
    return result
return getNode(treeNode.right_child(),key)
```

In this specific case, since `None` is falsey, you can use the `or` operator to do the "short-circuiting" for you:

```
return getNode(treeNode.left_child(),key) or getNode(treeNode.right_child(),key)
```

The second recursive call will only be made if the first one returned a falsey value (such as `None`).

Note that for some recursive algorithms, you may need to recurse multiple times unconditionally, then combine the results together before returning them. For instance, a function to add up the (numeric) key values in a tree might look something like this:

```
def sum_keys(node):
    if node is None:  # base case
        return 0
    left_sum = sumKeys(node.left_child())   # first recursion
    right_sum = sumKeys(node.right_child()) # second recursion
    return left_sum + right_sum + node.key  # add recursive results to our key and return
```

Comment: This is Perfect!  Both snippets work fine! Thank you so Much Blckknght!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your objects:

Three base cases:

- current node is `None` --> return None
- current node matches the key --> return it
- current node does not match, is the end of the branch --> return None

If not base case recurse.  Short circuit the recursion with `or`: return the left branch if it a match or return the right branch result (which might also be None)

```
def getNode(treeNode,key):
    if treeNode == None:
        return None
    elif treeNode.key == key:
        print("got it=",treeNode.key)
        return treeNode
    elif not any(treeNode.has_left_child(), treeNode.has_right_child()):
        return None
    #left_branch = getNode(treeNode.left_child(),key)    
    #right_branch = getNode(treeNode.right_child(),key)
    #return left_branch or right_branch
    return getNode(treeNode.left_child(),key) or getNode(treeNode.right_child(),key)
```

Comment: You may want to short-circuit the second recursive call, since it's not necessary if `left_branch` is not `None`. You could do one long line with `return getNode(treenode.left_child(), key) or getNode(treenode.right_child(), key)`, or you could split it up a bit more, maybe with an `if` statement.

Comment: Make it so it doen't go right if it finds something in left?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was suggesting. You can only return one result, so if you found one on the left branch, there's nothing useful you can get from recursing on the right branch. I'm not sure you can get rid of the check for `treeNode == None` though, since a node might have one child but not both.

Comment: I was a little fuzzy on how a treeNode could be None

Comment: Thanks Blckknght, the question is about how to traverse 2 branches without or with return.

Comment: wwii, the node cannot be None, but the function could return None if no node found.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `return`, use `yield`:

```
class Tree:
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
      self.__dict__ = {i:kwargs.get(i) for i in ['left', 'key', 'right']}

t = Tree(key=10, right=Tree(key=20, left=Tree(key=18)), left=Tree(key=5))
def find_val(tree, target):
  if tree.key == target:
    yield target
    print('found')
  else:
    if getattr(tree, 'left', None) is not None:
      yield from find_val(tree.left, target)
    if getattr(tree, 'right', None) is not None:
      yield from find_val(tree.right, target)

print(list(find_val(t, 18)))
```

Output:

```
found
[18]
```

However, you could also implement the `get_node` function as a method in your binary tree class by implementing a `__contains__` methods:

```
class Tree:
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
     self.__dict__ = {i:kwargs.get(i) for i in ['left', 'key', 'right']} 
   def __contains__(self, _val):
     if self.key == _val:
        return True
     _l, _r = self.left, self.right
     return _val in [[], _l][bool(_l)] or _val in [[], _r][bool(_r)]

t = Tree(key=10, right=Tree(key=20, left=Tree(key=18)), left=Tree(key=5))
print({i:i in t for i in [10, 14, 18]})
```

Output:

```
{10: True, 14: False, 18: True}
```

Comment: @DavidMa Glad to help! Please consider accepting this answer if it assisted you.